# Do the binary boolean operators have associativity?

Tags: c++, boolean, operators, associativity

Is `a && b && c` defined by the language to mean `(a && b) && c` or `a && (b && c)`?

Wow, Jerry was quick. To beef up the question: does it actually matter? Would there be an observable difference between `a && b && c` being interpreted as `(a && b) && c` or `a && (b && c)`?

Comment: Yes, it matters. Short-circuting would prevent some of your operands from being evaluated.

Comment: @meagar How would `(a && b) && c` differ from `a && (b && c)` with respect to short-circuiting? For example, how would `(false && b) && c` differ from `false && (b && c)`? Both expressions evaluate neither `b` nor `c`...

Comment: @FredOverflow if `a` is false, you are correct.  if `b` is false, `c` never gets evaluated.  Basically, if there is some `false` to the left of some AND'd conditions, the tests stop with it.

Comment: @ZacHowland: If `a` is true, and `b` is `false`, `c` doesn't get evaluated, regardless of whether you use `(a && b) && c` or `a && (b && c)`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Isn't that what I just said?

Comment: @ZacHowland: Did you?  I assumed you were stating that for only one of the two expressions, because your answer seems to indicate that you are of the opinion that associativity matters because of short-circuiting.  But if what I said in my comment is true, it does not.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I've updated my answer to be more clear.  What I was stating in the previous comment was simply that if you operate from left to right, the first `false` stops anything further right from being tested/executed.  With that in mind, it doesn't matter if you write `(a && b) && c` or `a && (b && c)` or `a && b && c` as they are all equivalent.  The only thing that does matter is the order of the operands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

§5.14/1: "The && operator groups left-to-right. [...] Unlike &, && guarantees left-to-right
evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false."

As to when or how it matters: I'm not sure it really does for built-in types. It's possible, however, to overload it in a way that would make it matter. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A;

class M {
    int x;
public:
    M(int x) : x(x) {}
    M &operator&&(M const &r); 
    M &operator&&(A const &r); 
    friend class A;
};

class A {
    int x;
    public:
    A(int x) : x(x) {}
    A &operator&&(M const &r); 
    A &operator&&(A const &r);
    operator int() { return x;}
    friend class M;
};

M & M::operator&&(M const &r) {
    x *= r.x;
    return *this;
}

M & M::operator&&(A const &r) {
    x *= r.x;
    return *this;
}

A &A::operator&&(M const &r) {
    x += r.x;
    return *this;
}

A &A::operator&&(A const &r) {
    x += r.x;
    return *this;
}

int main() {
    A a(2), b(3);
    M c(4);

    std::cout << ((a && b) && c) << "\n";
    std::cout << (a && (b && c)) << "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
9
16
```

Caveat: this only shows how it *can* be made to matter. I'm **not** particularly recommending that anybody do so, only showing that if you want to badly enough, you can create a situation in which it makes a difference.

Comment: I believe all binary operators of equivalent priority follow this convention.

Comment: Just to be clear, that means `(a && b) && c` and not `a && (b && c)`, right?

Comment: @ZacHowland: conditional operators and assignment (to name just two I can think of immediately) group right to left, so `a=b=c` is equivalent to `a=(b=c)`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Ah, good point.  I haven't chained assignments in so long that I didn't even think of it.

Answer (score 5):

In fact it is very important that the expression is computed from left to right. This is used to have short-circuit in some expressions. Here is a case where it does matter:

```
vector<vector<int> > a;
if (!a.empty()  && !a[0].empty() && a[0].back() == 3)
```

I bet you write similar statements few times a day. And if associativity was not defined you would be in huge trouble.

Comment: @FredOverflow right you are.I have added a way more practical and in fact common case.

Comment: If you add explicit parentheses to change the associativity of the expression, i.e. `if (!a.empty()  && (!a[0].empty() && a[0].back() == 3))` -- does it make a difference?  I don't think it does.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley no it does not. I believe my answer addresses an earlier version of the question where if the expression is evaluated left to right or right to left was included

Answer (score 5):

The `&&` and `||` operators short-circuit: if the operand on the left determines the result of the overall expression, the operand on the right will not even be evaluated.

Therefore, a mathematician would describe them as left-associative, e.g.
`a && b && c` ⇔ `(a && b) && c`, because to a mathematician that means `a` and `b` are considered first.  For pedagogical purposes, though, it might be useful to write `a && (b && c)` instead, to emphasize that *neither* `b` nor `c` will be evaluated if `a` is false.

Parentheses in C only change evaluation order when they override *precedence*.  Both `a && (b && c)`
and `(a && b) && c` will be evaluated as `a` first, then `b`, then `c`. Similarly, the evaluation order of both
`a + (b + c)` and `(a + b) + c` is unspecified.  Contrast `a + (b * c)` versus `(a + b) * c`, where the compiler is still free to evaluate `a`, `b`, and `c` in any order, but the parentheses determine whether the multiplication or the addition happens first.  Also contrast FORTRAN, where in at least some cases parenthesized expressions must be evaluated first.

Comment: Er, if by "it does not matter" you mean "`a && b && c` is evaluated strictly left to right regardless of parenthesization", then yes. See edit.

Comment: Interestingly, in Haskell, for example, `(&&)` and `(||)` are *right*-associative, which seems to make more sense. I don't understand why in JavaScript and Python they are left-associative.

Answer (score 2):

If `a && b` is false, then the `&& c` portion is never tested.  So yes, it does matter (at least in that you need to have your operations ordered from left to right).  `&&` is an associative operation by nature.

**Associative Property**

> Within an expression containing two or more occurrences in a row of
>   the same associative operator, the order in which the operations are
>   performed does not matter as long as the sequence of the operands is
>   not changed. That is, rearranging the parentheses in such an
>   expression will not change its value.

So it doesn't matter (logically) if you write it as `a && (b && c)` or `(a && b) && c`.  Both are equivalent.  But you cannot change the order of the operations (e.g `a && c && b` is not equivalent to `a && b && c`).

Comment: How would `(false && b) && c` differ from `false && (b && c)`? Both expressions evaluate neither `b` nor `c`...

Comment: In that case, you are correct.  The logical flow is simply from left to right, so when you reach your first `false` condition in a chain of conditions, it stops there.  Since `&&` is associative by nature, as long as you don't throw an `||` in there, it won't make much of a difference.  As soon as you have an `||` condition, the parentheses start to matter.